# Why strip not working?

Tags: python, strip

I have the following data in a huge string:

```
data="in West upto 19:17        &nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
in North from 19:17   "
```

I am trying to remove "'&nbsp ;'" from this huge string but it does not work with strip like this:

```
data= data.strip('&nbsp;')
```

Same output as before no change in text of data:

```
print(data)

in West upto 19:17        &nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
in North from 19:17
```

Why is there no change no stripping is happening all the &nbsp are present there and then?

Help Please!

Comment: strip() is used to remove white spaces

Comment: `strip()` only works at the start and end of a string not inside of it.

Comment: strip only removes from start and end of string. Use data.replace('&nbsp;','')

Comment: use `data.replace("&nbsp;", "")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) removes characters from the beginning of the line or the end of the line only. It does not modify those in between, so instances of the substring `&nbsp;` situated elsewhere in the string will not be removed. Also, `str.strip()` removes any of the characters in the given string, not the actual string.

You can use [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) to remove the substring `'&nbsp;'`:

```
data = data.replace('&nbsp;`, '')
```

Comment: xccepted due to higher quality

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably looking for is `replace` rather then `strip` is used to eliminate characters at the beginning or end of your text. By default it is removing spaces, but you can specify a character as well.

```
data.replace("&nbsp", "")
```

Comment: Please add some description. As it is your answer might be flagged as low quality.

Comment: This works I am unable to accept your answer as there is a Bot made wait of 6 minutes. Will accept once this time expires.

Comment: @KlausD. It does not matter if an answer is low quality or high it should work and this answer works for me.

Comment: Sounds good, If you think other answers were usefull too, you can upvote them and make people happy :D

Comment: @PuneetMathur: you should prefer the correct answers of higher quality. Those tend to be answers with some explanation. Also, your question does not ask for a solution, it asks for an _explanation_ as to _why_ `strip()` did not work as you expected. This answer (originally) did not provide that explanation.

Comment: agree in this answer there is no explanation and there is a mistake with a missing ";"